# python setup.py upload error

Tags: python, pip, setup.py, pypi

Contents of `setup.py`:

[image]

When I execute `python setup.py sdist upload`, the following error occurrs:

[image]

Comment: Please add your code, rather than a picture of your code. Ditto for error message.

Comment: Changed question structure. Fixed grammar. Still, you should remove the images and put the actual text.